# Anonymous function as jQuery plugin parameter

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

I made a jQuery plugin with a set of customizable parameters:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        param1: 100,
        ...
    }, options );
};
```

I'm trying to overwrite `param1` by an anonymous function, but no luck.

```
$('#selector').myPlugin({
    param1: function() {
        var result;
        // some actions to get the value to return...
        return result;
    }
});
```

Is it possible? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it will work depends on what actions you are doing in your anonymous function.